# Unable to make API call

Tags: rest-api, api

We are using angular to display UI and Salesforce is being used to maintain database. We have a REST API class created which has the urlMapping. This class is used to find the records. Now we need to call this API (url- /v1/UpdateCustomerRecords/*) in angular but we have no idea how to start. Below is the code snippet. Please suggest.

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------
*  Example json Query  *
{
"Customers": {
    "updateCustomers": [{
        "accountId": "0012500000dOg5l",
        "CustomerId": "a2D20000000ABCl"
    }, {
        "accountId": "0012500000dOg5l",
        "CustomerId": "a2D20000000JG5r"
    }]
}
}
*
*accountId = Id of the currently logged in user
*CustomerId = Id of the Customer record that the user selected for reassigning
*/
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/UpdateCustomerRecords/*')
global with sharing class REST_UpdateCustomerRecords_V1 {

@HttpPatch
global static CustomerResponse doPatch(Customers Customers) {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    CustomerResponse response = new CustomerResponse();

    response.updateCustomers = Customers.updateCustomers;

    //Make sure the data passed for this call is valid. If it is not then return an error stating the error
    validateInput(response);

    if(response.status == 'Failure'){

        return response;

    }

    List<Customer__c> cusList = new List<Customer__c>();
    Account currentAccount = new Account();

    //Start looping through the records to get updated
    for(integer i = 0; i < response.updateCustomers.size(); i++){

        Customer__c oldCustomer = [SELECT Id, Account__c FROM Customer__c WHERE Id = :response.updateCustomers[i].CustomerId LIMIT 1];

        currentAccount.Id = response.updateCustomers[i].accountId;
        currentAccount.Customer_details_to_be_moved_from__c = oldCustomer.Account__c;

        //Each time, create a Customer__c variable using the Customer Id and the Account Id. Then add that variable to a list of Customer__c
        Customer__c currentCustomer = new Customer__c(Id = response.updateCustomers[i].CustomerId, Account__c = response.updateCustomers[i].accountId);

        cusList.add(currentCustomer);

    }

    //Try to update those Customer records
    Try{

        update cusList;
        update currentAccount;

        if(cusList.size() > 1){

            //If the update works then return a Success message and state how many Customers were updated
            response.Status = 'Success';
            response.Message = cusList.size() + ' Customer records are now visible to you';
            response.errorCode = '000';

        }

        else if(cusList.size() == 1){

            //If the update works then return a Success message and state that Customer is now visible
            response.Status = 'Success';
            response.Message = 'That Customer record is now visible to you';
            response.errorCode = '000';

        }

    }


    return response;
}


global class CustomerResponse {
    public List<updateCustomers> updateCustomers;
    public String status;
    public String message;
    public String errorCode;
}

global class Customers{

    public List<updateCustomers> updateCustomers = new List<updateCustomers>();

}

global class updateCustomers{

    public string accountId;
    public string CustomerId;

}    
}
```

Comment: So basically you want to make an api call from JS, right?

Comment: Yes, We are using JS for front end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Authentication**

Before making an API call you would also need to perform [authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) into salesforce. This part requires much attention from your side as you have to decide which method you will use for authentication etc, There are typically three:

**Web server flow**, where the server can securely protect the consumer secret.

**User-agent flow**, used by applications that cannot securely store the consumer secret.

**Username-password flow**, where the application has direct access to user credentials.

**Step 2: After Authentication, Make a call:**

In JS you can make an API call like this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "Your Rest URL Here", false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
```

The base endpoint for Apex REST is 
https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/

**Resources:**

1. For calling the API from JS follow below link:

[How to call a REST web service API from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript-button-handler)

2. How to call Apex Rest class from outside of salesforce take a look at following blog, Try workbench example given in the blog to have in-depth understanding.

[Rest API in Salesforce | Execute Rest API on workbench](http://amitsalesforce.blogspot.in/2016/04/rest-api-in-salesforce-execute-rest-api.html)